# Почему - повеса?

Tags: этимология

Интересно, почему легкомысленных молодых людей, любящих приударить за девушками, называют повесами?
Мой вариант: они вешаются на девушек (но, с другой стороны, это обычно девушки вешаются на молодых людей).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сдается мне, что Ваша версия (о связи с "вешаться", "повесить") не лишена здравого зерна, но, конечно, не так прямо, чтоб так сразу - и на девушках. Более широко.

Точной этимологии я в словарях не видел, но подозреваю, что "повеса", "повесничать" восходит к "вешаться" в значении "искать развлечений", "добиваться расположения".

Answer (score 3):

Повеса — человек, ведущий праздный, легкомысленный образ жизни, проводящий время в проказах. Он, скорее, веселится, но никак не "вешается", например:
*Что за шум стоит кругом,

Музыка, веселье?

Видно Бахус к нам зашел —

Это без сомненья!

Он веселый хулиган,

Озорник, повеса!

Он всегда немного пьян

И не знает стресса.*

Веселый, озорной гуляка, молодой и веселый повеса — очень часто слова "веселый" и "повеса" стоят рядом. Стоит посмотреть этимологию для "веселого": слово общеславянское, в нашем языке ближайший родственник — это "весна", а в др.-инд. существовало слово *vasu* со значением "хорошо живущий, радующийся".

Так, может быть, повеса и весельчак — это родственники? Но пока это только версия, конкретная информация о происхождении и истории употребления слова пока не находится.

Answer (score 1):

Повеса – человек, праздношатающийся по городам и весям. Весь – селение. «И ходит он по весям без дела, только гуляет да пьёт!»

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решается проверкой орфографического написания в старых русских словарях. Из Словаря 1847 :
*Весь* - деревня, селенiе
*веселый*
*вѣсить*
*повѣса* - шалунъ, вѣтреникъ, рѣзвый...

Даль пишет в статье "Повисать" :

> **Повеса** обл. шалун, шалопай, проказник, **висляй**, резвый и нередко докучливый баловник; невежливый, дерзкий шалун. Он только повесничает (висляйничает), а дела не делает. Наповесничался, так и пришел домой. Так за(ис)повесничался, что никуда негоден. Повесничанье к добру не ведет. Повесничество не промысел.

САР 1789-94 :

> *Повѣса* ... развращенной, шалунЪ, вѣтреникЪ. *Едакая повѣса*.

Comment: Повисать, висляйничать  - это зависать? "Мы тут с ребятами в баре зависли"? Еще "зависать на ком-то" - надоедать своим присутствием, быть назойливым, "докучливым".

Comment: Объединение "повесы" и "зависать" - это плюс!
Но "зависать", наверное, значит не "веселиться", а скорее "брать паузу": Компьютер завис. 

Понятно, что затянувшаяся пауза ведёт к деградации личности, посему "повесничанье к добру не ведёт".

Answer (score 0):

По- означает- здесь-Б в иврите и вошло в том же значении во множество русских слов как к примеру-поселение ,пошел ,побережье, повеление и прочее.
Веса действительно загадка. Насчет веселья могло бы быть и повесел.
Я бы взвесил 2 других варианта. Первый- весь. Повеса значит тут весь он в этом случае. Второй -веще,вещать,вещающий. Также как знающий -зная,вещающий дает-веща. Отсюда -повеща и потом щ превратилось в звук -с повеса. Здесь вещатель другими словами.